# Google Cloud Platform How to change the billing project-id of a client-id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-key, clientid

Hello I have a service that uses my business client-id + secret to retrieve datas from Directions API.

While I was trying to analyze some problems I noticed that the client id is accociated to a specific projetc-id .(I feagured out analizing the traffic)

The questions are:
1. Is there a way to move the traffic generated from my client-id to another project?
2. where can I find informations about the configuration of the client ID with permissions, quotas ecc...?

Thanks a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to move the traffic generated from my client-id to
>   another project?

No, you cannot move the Client ID to another Project. You can create new credentials in the other project.

> where can I find informations about the configuration of the client ID
>   with permissions, quotas ecc...?

You do not assign permissions or quotas to Client ID Credentials. This is done thru IAM member permissions (IAM Roles).

Start with this link: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview

This is a good video: [Better Practices for Cloud IAM (Cloud Next '18)](https://youtu.be/ZMC8Ng3E3LQ)